# pandas replace first few 0s with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace first consecutive 0s of a DataFrame with np.nan for each columns. For example, I want to convert:

```
pd_tmp_start = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[0,0.3],[1.2,0.4],[0,0]])
print pd_tmp_start

     0    1
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.3
2  1.2  0.4
3  0.0  0.0
```

to

```
pd_tmp_target = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,0.3],[1.2,0.4],[0,0]])
print pd_tmp_target

     0    1
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.3
2  1.2  0.4
3  0.0  0.0
```

So, what i do is

```
pd_tmp_start[pd_tmp_start.cumsum()==0] = np.nan
```

Although it works. However, I got the warning

> /home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:1:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

Any idea what is the correct way to do so? Thank you.

Edit: for some reason, the previous code does not output the warning, but when I work on my complex Dataframe and perform `pd_tmp_start[pd_tmp_start().cumsum()==0] = np.nan`

The warning pops out....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `cumprod` and `mask`:

```
pd_tmp_start.mask(pd_tmp_start.eq(0).cumprod().astype(bool))
```

Output:

```
    0    1
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.3
2  1.2  0.4
3  0.0  0.0
```

## Update for comment below:

```
pd_tmp_start.mask(pd_tmp_start.eq(0).cumprod().astype(bool),-9876)
```

Output:

```
        0       1
0 -9876.0 -9876.0
1 -9876.0     0.3
2     1.2     0.4
3     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: This is great. The more important question is actually, if I do not want to set it to np.nan. I want to set it to for example -9876 instead... How should I set it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [DataFrame.mask()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method:

```
In [67]: pd_tmp_start = pd_tmp_start.mask(pd_tmp_start.cumsum()==0)

In [68]: pd_tmp_start
Out[68]:
     0    1
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.3
2  1.2  0.4
3  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: This is great. The more important question is actually, if I do not want to set it to np.nan. I want to set it to for example -9876 instead... How should I set it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `()` after `pd_tmp_start`

```
pd_tmp_start[(pd_tmp_start.cumsum()==0)]=np.nan
pd_tmp_start
Out[604]: 
     0    1
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  0.3
2  1.2  0.4
3  0.0  0.0
```